# PHP insert into a table not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-into

I'm trying to insert items into a table but it isn't working although it's displaying a successful message :/

Here's my code & table.

```
<?php 
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "error.log");
    error_log( "Hello, errors!" );

        $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
        $itemDesc = $_POST['itemDesc'];
        $itemSlutID = $_POST['itemSlutID'];

            if (isset($_POST['addBtn'])){

                if (empty($itemName) || empty($itemDesc) || empty($itemSlutID)){
                    echo error('Please fill in all fields');

                }else{
                    $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `items` VALUES(NULL, :userID, :itemName, :itemDesc, :itemSlutID)");
                    $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':userID' => $_SESSION['ID'], ':itemName' => $itemName, ':itemDesc' => $itemDesc, ':itemSlutID' => $itemSlutID));
                    echo success('Item has been added, please wait up to 1 hour for us to approve the item.');
                }
            }
?>

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemName` text NOT NULL,
  `itemDesc` text NOT NULL,
  `itemSlutID` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it display a success message? You uncondintioanlly do that echo, without ever checking what your DB calls returned. your code is basically. "I don't care that that universe blew up and everyone's dead, I'm going to pretend like nothing happened".

Comment: `:itemSlutID` one has to wonder what this site's about.

Comment: `error_log( "Hello, errors!" );` yeah, most likely. and in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Marc meant *"unconditionally"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a marketplace.
SlutID stands for slut.io (ecommerce service) item id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. `null`

Look at your first column:

`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,

Yet your first placeholder value is `NULL`. Better practice would be to change it to `NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

### 2. Saying "success" whatever happens

After the statement executes, you're not checking to see if it was *successful* - you're just echoing a statement.

Change:

```
$SQLinsert -> execute(array(':userID' => $_SESSION['ID'], ':itemName' => $itemName, ':itemDesc' => $itemDesc, ':itemSlutID' => $itemSlutID));
echo success('Item has been added, please wait up to 1 hour for us to approve the item.');
```

To:

```
if($SQLinsert -> execute(array(':userID' => $_SESSION['ID'], ':itemName' => $itemName, ':itemDesc' => $itemDesc, ':itemSlutID' => $itemSlutID))){
    echo success('Item has been added, please wait up to 1 hour for us to approve the item.');
} else {
    //There's been a problem!
    echo "ERROR: " . $SQLinsert->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.

Comment: @SevnDK No worries. If it helped, don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Spot the problem:

```
$SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `items` VALUES(NULL, :userID, :itemName, :itemDesc, :itemSlutID)");
                                                          ^--- ID field


CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
                ^^^^^
```

Since you never bothered to check if the query actually succeeded, and blindly (and WRONGLY) output a false "success" message, you ended up here...

Why are you inserting a null value into a field you've explicitly defined as "not null"?